# How to see each sub-query memory used in Presto UI

Tags: presto

In `presto-ip:port/ui/` site.

When I go to -> Query Overview -> Live Plan, I see Stage 6 Output 371MB data(which it's a lot for me).

How could I find out which part of the query it belong to? I click on Stage 6 and not showing usefull messaage.

[image: steps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the UI won't tell you that. However, you can run

```
EXPLAIN (TYPE DISTRIBUTED) <query>;
```

to see what are the stages, including what source table they are reading.

Also, there is a UI change proposal https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/10845 that, when included, will show the table name right in "tablescan" box in the UI.